# Smallest region that can contain all free $n$-ominoes.

Tags: extremal-combinatorics, oeis, polyomino

A nine-cell region is the smallest subset of the plane that can contain all twelve free [pentominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentomino), as illustrated below. (A free polyomino is one that can be rotated and flipped.)

A twelve-cell region is the smallest subset of the plane the can contain all $35$ free [hexominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexomino).

[image: Nine-cell region of the plane.]

---

What is the smallest region of the plane that can contain all $108$ free [heptominoes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heptomino) (shown below)? All $369$ free octominoes?

[image: free 7-ominos]

---

Also, is there an existing OEIS sequence for this? If not, I'll add one once there is a bit more data. (The sequence begins $1, 2, 4, 6, 9, 12, \cdots$.)

Comment: If $a(n)$ is the minimum size region covering all $n$-ominoes, then I've constructed examples to show $a(7) \leq 17$, $a(8) \leq 22$ and $a(9) \leq 26$.

Comment: And $a(10) \leq 32$.

Comment: You can make the bound $a(n) \leq n \cdot \left\lceil \dfrac{n}{2} \right\rceil$. It's not very good though.

Comment: For the heptomino case, a search over all shapes containable in a $4 \times 7$ bbox only return regions of size $17$. I don't know how to extend the emulation to $5 \times 7$ bbox but this is a strong indication that $a(7) = 17$.

Comment: if I didn' make any mistake, $a(8) \le 20$. example container `00000111-00000111-00111111-11111111`

Comment: @achillehui, my program confirmed that this container works, so indeed $a(8) \leq 20$.

Comment: I submitted a [related computational challenge](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/167484/53884) over at Programming Puzzles & Code Golf Stack Exchange.

Comment: Some upper bounds$$\begin{array}{rcl}
n & a(n)\le & \text{example container}\\
\hline
 7 & 17 & \small\verb/11-111-11111-1111111/\\
 8 & 20 & \small\verb/111-111-111111-11111111/\\
 9 & 27 & \small\verb/111-111-11111-1111111-111111111/\\
10 & 31 & \small\verb/111-1111-111111-11111111-1111111111/\\
11 & 38 & \small\verb/111-1111-1111-1111111-111111111-11111111111/\\
12 & 43 & \small\verb/1111-1111-11111-11111111-1111111111-111111111111/
\end{array}$$